# Element deletion in single linked list at head not working

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, singly-linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
   int data;
   struct node *next;
};

struct node *head = NULL;
struct node *second = NULL;
struct node *third = NULL;

void insertAtBeg(struct node *n, int data) {
    struct node *temp;
    temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
}
void insertAtEnd(struct node *n, int data) {
    struct node *temp;
    temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    while (n->next != NULL) {
        n = n->next;
    }
    n->next = temp;
}
void deleteElement(struct node *head, int data) {
    if (head->data == data) {
        struct node *temp;
        temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(temp);
        printf("after deletion at head in function\n");
        printList(head);
    }
}
void printList(struct node *n) {
    while (n != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", n->data);
        n = n->next;
    }
}
void main() {
    head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    second = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    third = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->data = 1;
    head->next = second;
    second->data = 2;
    second->next = third;
    third->data = 3;
    third->next = NULL;
    printList(head);
    insertAtBeg(head, 0);
    printf("after insertion at beginning\n");
    printList(head);
    insertAtEnd(head, 4);
    printf("after insertion at End\n");
    printList(head);
    deleteElement(head, 0);
    printf("after deletion at head in main\n");
    printList(head);
}
```

output of the code is

```
1
2
3
after insertion at beginning
0
1
2
3
after insertion at End
0
1
2
3
4
after deletion at head in function
1
2
3
4
after deletion at head in main
0
1
2
3
4
```

Why is there a difference in output of the function called in main and the function called in another function.ie.after deletion at head in function and after deletion at head in main, when both are supposed to be deleting element from the same list

Comment: You are only changing a local copy of head

Comment: @stark You may need to be more specific. Which function are you referring to? The code is all over the place - some functions use the global `head` and some don't.

Comment: Th one in the title

Comment: One of the problems with C is you tell beginners not to use global variables, which work, and then they pass pointers, which gets confusing.  The reason its confusing is that the name head means both the pointer and the node it points to.  Getting that right with call-by-value is a challenge.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you need a way to modify the head of the list when inserting and/or deleting elements from the list.

A simple way to do this is for these functions to return a potentially updated value of the head pointer and for the caller to store this return value into it's `head` variable.

Here is a modified version of your code with these semantics:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
   int data;
   struct node *next;
};

struct node *insertAtBeg(struct node *head, int data) {
    struct node *temp;
    temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    // should test for memory allocation failure
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = head;
    return temp;
}
struct node *insertAtEnd(struct node *head, int data) {
    struct node *temp;
    struct node *n;
    temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    // should test for memory allocation failure
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL)
        return temp;
    n = head;
    while (n->next != NULL) {
        n = n->next;
    }
    n->next = temp;
    return head;
}
struct node *deleteElement(struct node *head, int data) {
    // delete the first node with a given data
    if (head->data == data) {
        struct node *temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(temp);
    } else {
        struct node *n = head;
        while (n->next != NULL) {
            if (n->next->data == data) {
                struct node *temp = n->next;
                n->next = temp->next;
                free(temp);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return head;
}
void printList(const struct node *n) {
    while (n != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", n->data);
        n = n->next;
    }
}
int main() {
    struct node *head = NULL;
    head = insertAtBeg(head, 1);
    head = insertAtEnd(head, 2);
    head = insertAtEnd(head, 3);
    printList(head);
    head = insertAtBeg(head, 0);
    printf("after insertion at beginning\n");
    printList(head);
    head = insertAtEnd(head, 4);
    printf("after insertion at End\n");
    printList(head);
    head = deleteElement(head, 0);
    printf("after deletion at head in main\n");
    printList(head);
    // should free the list
    return 0;
}
```

An alternative is to pass the address of the list head pointer so the function can modify it if needed.

Here is a modified version of your code with this alternative approach:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
   int data;
   struct node *next;
};

struct node *insertAtBeg(struct node **headp, int data) {
    struct node *temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));
    if (temp != NULL) {
        temp->data = data;
        temp->next = *headp;
        *headp = temp;
    }
    return temp;
}
struct node *insertAtEnd(struct node **headp, int data) {
    struct node *temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));
    if (temp != NULL) {
        temp->data = data;
        temp->next = NULL;
        if (*headp == NULL) {
            *headp = temp;
        } else {
            struct node *n = *headp;
            while (n->next != NULL) {
                n = n->next;
            }
            n->next = temp;
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
int deleteElement(struct node **headp, int data) {
    // delete the first node with a given data
    struct node *head = *headp;
    if (head->data == data) {
        *headp = head->next;
        free(temp);
        return 1;  // node was found and freed
   } else {
        struct node *n = head;
        while (n->next != NULL) {
            if (n->next->data == data) {
                struct node *temp = n->next;
                n->next = temp->next;
                free(temp);
                return 1;  // node was found and freed
            }
        }
        return 0;  // node not found
    }
}
void printList(const struct node *n) {
    while (n != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", n->data);
        n = n->next;
    }
}
int main() {
    struct node *head = NULL;
    insertAtBeg(&head, 1);
    insertAtEnd(&head, 2);
    insertAtEnd(&head, 3);
    printList(head);
    insertAtBeg(&head, 0);
    printf("after insertion at beginning\n");
    printList(head);
    insertAtEnd(&head, 4);
    printf("after insertion at End\n");
    printList(head);
    deleteElement(&head, 0);
    printf("after deletion at head in main\n");
    printList(head);
    // free the list
    while (head != NULL) {
        deleteElement(&head, head->data);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This alternative approach uses double pointers, so it is a bit more difficult for beginners to comprehend, but it has a strong advantage: the functions can update the list pointer **and** provide a meaningful return value that can be tested to detect errors. For example `insertAtBeg()` and `insertAtEnd()` return `NULL` if the new node could not be allocated but preserve the list. Similarly `deleteElement()` can return an indicator showing whether the element was found or not.

With this approach, you can write functions to pop the first or last element of the list, or the one at a given index, or one with a given `data`, while updating the list pointer as needed.

Comment: The code is working fine now.It was my  assumption that argument that is passed to the function is call by reference and it would modify the existing list.Is my assumption wrong?

Comment: @AnushaChinapana: in C arrays are passed as a pointer to their first element and all other data objects are passed by value. To emulate *passing by reference*, you must pass a pointer to the object you want the function to modify. In my answer, I don't do that, I simply return the head of the list, which can be the same or a different pointer depending on which node was added/removed. This return value must be stored into its own list pointer by the caller, as you can see in `main()`.

Comment: @AnushaChinapana: I updated the answer with an alternative approach, passing the address of the list pointer. The method is more powerful and a good solution when you need to update the list pointer **and** return a value.

Answer (score 0):

In the function void deleteElement(struct node *head,int data) you are passing a pointer to the head node.  If you make changes to the node, then that works because you are pointing to the actual node.  However, the variable `head` is a local copy of the pointer, which is not the one in main.  When you change head to head->next that is only changing the local copy, so it has no effect outside deleteElement.

ADVANCED LEVEL POINTERS

To actually change head you have to pass a pointer to it, making a double pointer:

```
void deleteElement(struct node **phead,int data) {
    struct node *temp;
    temp = *phead;
    *phead = (*phead)->next;
```

this means you have to pass the address of head `&head` as the parameter.

Comment: What is an `advanced level pointer`?  Your answer is shaping up nicely, but I would consider removing that sub-title.  It is confusing to suggest something is advanced when it is really just pointers.